# C# derived interface cannot work properly in C++

Tags: c#, c++, com, interface, import

I have two interfaces defined in C#, as below:

```
[Guid("4938540B-3DB2-452c-A061-59EC499657E7")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IRADevice
{
   Void FA();
}

/// <summary>
/// IRADevice interface represents a given RADevice.
/// </summary>
[Guid("4938540B-3DB2-452c-A061-59EC499657E8")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IRADevice2 : IRADevice
{
    void FB();
}
```

In c++ code, I import the tlb produced by above interface using following command

```
#import "device.tlb"  raw_interfaces_only
```

The created tlh file is as below:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("4938540b-3db2-452c-a061-59ec499657e7"))
IRADevice : IDispatch
{
//
// Raw methods provided by interface
//

virtual HRESULT __stdcall FA ( ) = 0;
};

struct __declspec(uuid("4938540b-3db2-452c-a061-59ec499657e8"))
IRADevice2 : IDispatch
{
//
// Raw methods provided by interface
//

virtual HRESULT __stdcall FB ( ) = 0;
};
```

I expect IRADevice derives from IRADevice not from IDispatch, and includes FA function. Can anybody tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: Did you try to remove InterfaceType attribute from the derived interface(IRADevice2)?

Comment: This is a well known limitation in the CLR's support for COM interop. You'll need to flatten the derived interface, simply repeat the methods from IRADevice. Put them in the same order, before the IRADevice2 specific methods.

Comment: I tried to remove InterfaceType attribute from the derived interface(IRADevice2), does not work.

Comment: This is how COM works. You have to call the QueryInterface method to cast an IRADevice2 to IRADevice and viceversa.

Answer (score 2):

As @HansPassant stated this is a known limitation. It took me a minute but I found some relevant documentation to support that fact. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx

The most relevant portion being:

*COM interfaces declared in C# must include declarations for all members of their base interfaces with the exception of members of IUnknown and IDispatch — the .NET Framework automatically adds these. COM interfaces which derive from IDispatch must be marked with the InterfaceType attribute.*